# How can I allow my webparts to share js variables in sharepoint 2007

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, variables

I am working in MOSS 2007 and have a page which contains two page utilities(very similar to iframes but in corasworks webpart form)

The first is pointing to an aspx page which contains a custom display adaptor which allows me to use xslt and html, and a content editor pointing to a txt file with the majority my javascripts.

As for the second it points to a different aspx which also contains a different custom display adaptor and a content editor which points to the same txt file for the scripts.

On the file for the scripts I have a global variable, I am testing it's value by using an alert on both webparts and both alerts show the initial value at first, but when I change the value of that variable with the first webpart and try the alerts again on both, I get the changed value only on the first, but still the original value when it is shown on the second.

I ultimately would like to have the second and show the changed value as the first does, but apparently I am not accessing or storing this correctly
I believe this could be a parent/child issue but cannot seem to pass the variable back and forth between the two can anyone propose a suggestion as to how to go about doing this?

It would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: JS variables can only be trivially made "global" within the same "window" context. You can access other window contexts via `window.frame[..].window` or `window.parent.window` as appropriate, for same-domain pages, but that becomes terribly messy after a short while.

Comment: I can imagine.. is it necessary to specify any specific id of the webpart when trying to access this?

Comment: The Web Part ID is not related: "very similar to iframes but in corasworks webpart form" -- are frames/iframes used?

Comment: Oh ok, but no I have not coded any frames/iframes on the page.  The page utilities I was refering to are a webpart which basically has the same function as an iframe which is how I bring up the aspx pages